# Also want my cake

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

### Introduction

[image]Today is my birthday,

Yes my parents spend a lot time at home during the cold December [**holidays**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57277/its-my-birthday-d) as many [**others**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57597/the-great-british-cake-off?lq=1).

So I also want my cake.

But I have a problem: I just sent the invitations today so I'm not sure how many friends will come. Also I don't want to order a big cake because I have been on a diet since last year and don't want to keep temptation leftovers in the fridge.

### Challenge

Write a full program to output the cake design so my baker prepares just *enough* cake for everyone.

Input Integer `1 <= n <= 999`.  Worst case I eat my cake [**alone**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ikO4vBwNHWk).

- Each slice will have a unique label number `1 .. n` sequenced left to right, then top to bottom.
- Write in the middle line and align center the best way you can.
- Slice size is a square of 3x3 (this is why upper limit is 999).
- `*` indicate where to cut each slice.

### Output

n = 1 => Side = RoundUP(sqrt(1)) = 1

```
*****
*   *
* 1 *
*   *
*****
```

n = 3 => Side = RoundUP(sqrt(3)) = 2

```
*********
*   *   *
* 1 * 2 *
*   *   *
*********
*   *
* 3 *
*   *
*****
```

n = 5 => Side = RoundUP(sqrt(5)) = 3

```
*************
*   *   *   *
* 1 * 2 * 3 *
*   *   *   *
*************
*   *   *
* 4 * 5 *
*   *   *
*********
```

n = 10 => Side = RoundUP(sqrt(10)) = 4

```
*****************
*   *   *   *   *
* 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 *
*   *   *   *   *
*****************
*   *   *   *   *
* 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 *
*   *   *   *   *
*****************
*   *   *  
* 9 * 10*
*   *   *
*********
```

### Winning

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Happy Birthday!

Comment: Oh God, what have I started?! D: We need a [tag:cake] tag now ;)

Comment: What can I say september have a lot of bdays :)

Comment: @BetaDecay Can you point me to how create the leader board?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5139/leaderboard-snippet

Comment: Do the numbers have to be as shown: 1 (and presumably 3) digits centred, and 2 digits right of centre? Or can they be justified in whatever way is easiest?

Comment: `Worst case I eat my cake alone.` - I consider this the best case scenario.

Comment: [Relevant xkcd](http://xkcd.com/1512/)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>241</s> <s>239</s> 237 bytes

```
i=input()
s=int(round(i**.5+.5))
q="*"*5;p="*   *"
v=lambda x,y:"\x1b[%d;%dH".join(["",q,p,"*{}*",p,q])%tuple(i for j in zip(range(x*4+1,x*4+6),[y*4+5]*5)for i in j)
print"".join([v(j/s,j%s).format(`j+1`.center(3," "))for j in range(i)])
```

Lots of ANSI goodness...

Defines a function for drawing a box at a position on the screen.

Then calls it with the relevant positions that are in the cake.

Finally adds the numbers using `str.format()` and `str.center`

NOTE: If your terminal isn't big enough to display everything at once, it will get 'cropped' and you won't be able to see anything past the last row.