# Monday Mini-Golf #7: Simplify ingredient measurements

Tags: code-golf, number, conversion

**Monday Mini-Golf:** A series of short [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenges, posted (hopefully!) every Monday.
<sub>Sorry it's late; I realized 90% of the way through writing out a different idea that it was a duplicate.</sub>

My family is rather large, so we eat a lot of food. We usually need to double, triple, or even quadruple recipes to make enough food! But as multiplying the measurements can be a pain, it'd be nice to have a program to do this for us.

## Challenge

Your challenge is to create a program or function that takes in a measurement as a number *N* and a letter *L*, and returns the same measurement, simplified as much as possible. Here's the required measurement units (all are American, like my family), and their corresponding letters:

```
1 cup (c) = 16 tablespoons (T) = 48 teaspoons (t)
1 pound (l) = 16 ounces (o)
1 gallon (g) = 4 quarts (q) = 8 pints (p) = 128 fluid ounces (f)
```

"simplified as much as possible" means:

- Using the largest measurement unit possible. Each unit can have a remainder of 1/4, 1/3, 1/2, 2/3, or 3/4.
- Turning the result into a mixed number, if necessary.

For example, `4 o` is four ounces, which becomes `1/4 l`, a quarter pound. `8 t`, 8 teaspoons, becomes `2 2/3 T`.

### Details

- The input may be taken in any reasonable format; same with output. (`1 t`, `1,"t"`, `1\nt`, etc.)
- Make sure any fractional part is dealt with properly. (`11/4` in place of `1 1/4` is not allowed.)
- The number will always be a mixed number, and will always have a denominator of `2`, `3`, or `4` (or none). (no `1 1/8 T`, no `1.5 T`, etc.)
- As a result of the above, no downward conversions (e.g. cups to tablespoons) are ever needed.
- The letter will always be one of the letters listed above (`Tcfglopqt`).

## Test-cases

Here's an large list, hopefully covering all types of cases:

```
Input   | Output
--------+--------
1/2 t   | 1/2 t
3/4 t   | 1/4 T
1 t     | 1/3 T
1 1/2 t | 1/2 T
2 t     | 2/3 T
2 1/4 t | 3/4 T
2 1/2 t | 2 1/2 t
3 t     | 1 T
10 t    | 3 1/3 T
16 t    | 1/3 c
5 1/3 T | 1/3 c
8 T     | 1/2 c
16 T    | 1 c
36 T    | 2 1/4 c
1/4 c   | 1/4 c
1024 c  | 1024 c
1 o     | 1 o
4 o     | 1/4 l
5 1/3 o | 1/3 l
5 2/3 o | 5 2/3 o
8 o     | 1/2 l
28 o    | 1 3/4 l
28 l    | 28 l
2 f     | 2 f
4 f     | 1/4 p
8 f     | 1/4 q
16 f    | 1/2 q
32 f    | 1/4 g
64 f    | 1/2 g
128 f   | 1 g
2/3 p   | 1/3 q
1 1/3 p | 2/3 q
2 p     | 1/4 g
1 q     | 1/4 g
```

## Scoring

Our kitchen is very small, so the code should be as short as possible, so as not to make the kitchen more cramped. Shortest valid code in bytes wins; tiebreaker goes to submission that reached its final byte count first. The winner will be chosen next Monday, Nov 9. Good luck!

<sup>Please note that this challenge is similar to, but not a duplicate of, [World Big Dosa](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54224/world-big-dosa).</sup>

Comment: [Closely related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54224/world-big-dosa).

Comment: @AlexA. Ah, yes, I forgot to link to that. IMHO, it's sufficiently different: 1) it takes a different input format. 2) the output is quite a bit different. 3) more conversion types are required. 3a) the 1/8 measurement is not used.

Comment: @ETHproductions similiar spirit is equivalent to duplicate.

Comment: This'd never happen in proper, excuse me, metric units ;)

Comment: Your golfs are getting less and less mini.

Comment: @Dennis Yeah, sorry about that. This time, it happened for two reasons: 1) I didn't check for duplicity before writing out the original challenge. It was about continued fractions, and I found three of which it might be called out as duplicate. 2) I didn't try writing out a program myself to see how hard it would be. I'll make sure these things don't happen again in the future.

Comment: I'm sorry, but for personal reasons, I won't be able to be on PPCG as often as I have been. This means I won't be able to continue writing these challenges for a while. Hopefully I will continue this series in the future.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>349 334 330</s> 322 bytes

This answer section felt a little lonely. So uh, here's my attempt. Input should be given as in the test cases.

```
n=ToExpression@StringSplit@InputString[];i=#~Mod~1&;b=#&@@n;If[Length@n==3,{x,y,z}=n,{x,y,z}=If[IntegerQ@b,{b,0,Last@n},{0,b,Last@n}]];v={0,1/4,1/3,1/2,2/3,3/4};s=<|T->16,t->3,o->16,q->4,p->2,f->16|>;r=<|T->c,t->T,o->l,f->p,p->q,q->g|>;If[v~MemberQ~i[a=(x+y)/s@z],{x,y,z}={Floor@a,i@a,r@z}]~Do~3;Print@Row[{x,y,z}/. 0->""]
```

### Explanation

First get the user input, split that input on whitespace, and assign that to `n`. `i=#~Mod~1&` creates a function that gets the fractional part of a number, by taking it mod 1. `b=#&@@n` will simply get the first item in `n`; that would be everything up to the first space.

If `n` is 3 elements long, that means we have an integer, a fraction, *and* a unit. `{x,y,z}=n` will assign `x`, `y` and `z` to be the three parts of `n`.
The other case is that `n` is not 3 elements long; that means it’ll be 2 elements long instead. To stay consistent with above, we want `x` to be the integer part, `y` to be the fraction, and `z` the unit. So in this case, we need to check:

- If `b` (the first element of `n`) is an integer, then `x=b`, `y=0` and `z=Last@n` (the last element of `n`).
- If `b` isn’t an integer, that means we only have a fraction with no integer. So we want to swap `x` and `y` from above; instead, `x=0`, `y=b`, and `z` is the same as above.

Now we need to set up some lists:

`v = {0, 1/4, 1/3, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4}` is the list of acceptable fractions, as stated in the question.

`s = <|T -> 16, t -> 3, o -> 16, q -> 4, p -> 2, f -> 16|>` is an association (key-value pair, like a dictionary in Python) that represents the amount needed of a given unit to go “up” to one of the next largest unit. For example, `o -> 16` is because 16 ounces are required before we go up to 1 pound.

`r = <|T -> c, t -> T, o -> l, f -> p, p -> q, q -> g|>` is the association that actually represents what the next unit up is. For example, `T -> c` means one unit larger than Tablespoons is cups.

`If[v~MemberQ~i[a = (x + y)/s@z], {x, y, z} = {Floor@a, i@a, r@z}]~Do~3`

Now, the maximum number of times we need to go up a unit is 3; that would be fluid ounces (f) -> pints (p) -> quarts (q) -> gallon (g). So, now we do the following 3 times:

- Add `x` and `y`, (the integer and fractional parts)
- From the `s` association above, get element `z`; that is, access the current unit, and get the corresponding value in that association.
- Divide (x+y) by that value we got above, assign it to `a`, then get its fractional part.
- If that part is in the list `v`, then we can go up one unit; set `x` to `a` rounded down (integer part), set `y` to the fractional part of `a`, then access the association `r` with the current unit `z` to get the next unit up, and set that to `z`.
- If it’s *not* part of `v` instead, we don’t do anything, since it can’t be simplified.

Once that’s done 3 times, we print out the result:

`Print@Row[{x,y,z}/. 0->””]`

This simply prints out `{x,y,z}` in a row, but replaces any zeroes (if there’s no integer, or no fraction), with an empty string, so those don’t print out.