# Mixed Number to an Improper Fraction

Tags: code-golf, number, parsing, rational-numbers

In this challenge you will be converting a mixed number to an improper fraction.

Because improper fractions use fewer numbers, your code will need to be as short as possible.

---

### Examples

```
4 1/2
9/2

12 2/4
50/4

0 0/2
0/2

11 23/44
507/44
```

### Specification

You may assume the denominator of the input will never be 0. The input will always be in the format `x y/z` where x,y,z are arbitrary nonnegative integers. You do not need to simplify the output.

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/17239/8478) [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/62871/8478) [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54224/8478) (More or less. These are all about mixed fractions.)

Comment: You should add the tag "parsing". I'm sure most answers will spend more bytes on parsing the input and formatting the output than on doing the math.

Comment: Can the output be a rational number type or does it have to be a string?

Comment: @nimi Parsing isn't the primary goal of the challenge though.

Comment: @AlexA.: ... but a large part of the challenge. According to it's description the tag should be used in such cases.

Comment: Can `x`, `y` and `z` be negative?

Comment: @Dennis no, it can't

Comment: Is it okay to output `0` for the third test case?

Comment: Is the output format strict, or is the numerator on one line and the denominator on another line acceptable (i.e., instead of a `/` between, it's a newline)?

Comment: Can we take the input as an array of ASCII values? (This is basically what strings are in C).

Comment: @Challenger5 If your language is natively uses pointers for strings, you can take it in as a null-terminated string (array of ascii-values)

Comment: @Downgoat Well it's not actually a C submission, I just added that as justification for why it should be allowed.

Comment: @Challenger5 If your language is JS/Python/Java/one which has a native string datatype a string is a string so you can't take an array of integers for example in those languages.

Comment: @Downgoat Mine has no string datatype, only arrays and numbers.

Comment: @Downgoat Actually, can I assume it's null terminated anyways? (This is a stretch but it's helpful for golfing)

Comment: Based on the challenge I'm assuming it is, but is the input format "x y/z" mandatory, or can the space be a new-line,  and/or the `x,y,z` be separated inputs? Most answers are assuming the input format is indeed mandatory to be `x y/z`, but some aren't, hence this question to have a definitive answer.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Well, the question body does mention *The input will always be in the format `x y/z`*, so I think it's mandatory (although that's not very recommended).

Comment: Is extra whitespace allowed in the output? I have [this potential answer](https://bbrk24.github.io/Trilangle/?i=11%2023%2F44#%3F%3F%2CS*%2B%3F'!oS2%22%2C!zj%2F%2C%40) that prints an extra newline in the middle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Japt, 10 bytes

Woohoo, currently beating CJam!

```
U*W+V+'/+W
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VSpXK1YrJy8rVw==&input=MTEgMjMvNDQ=)

#### How it works

```
       // Implicit: [U,V,W] = eval(input). This automatically discards the slash.
U*W+V  // Calculate the new numerator: (whole part * denominator) + numerator.
+'/+W  // Add the slash and the denominator.
       // Implicit: output last expression
```

Comment: I spent a good bit of time yesterday trying to figure out how I had earned 15 rep off of an answer, until I realized: my first green checkmark! \o/

Answer (score 11):

## LabVIEW, 29 [LabVIEW Primitives](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7589/39490)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

### CJam, <s>16</s> <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
l'/']er~:Xb'/X
```

or

```
l'/']er~_@b'/@
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l'%2F'%5Der~%3AXb'%2FX&input=11%2023%2F44)

### Explanation

```
l      e# Read input.
'/']er e# Replace the "/" with a "]".
~      e# Evaluate the string as code. If the input was "i n/d", this pushes [i n] d.
:X     e# Store the denominator in X.
b      e# Treat [i n] as base-d digits. This effectively computes i*d + n.
'/     e# Push a slash.
X      e# Push the denominator.
```

The other version avoids using a variable by using a bit more stack shifting.

Comment: I really need to start using base conversion in CJam more.

Comment: An alternate version: `'//~\S/1$b'/@`, this is 13 bytes. *Edit*: oh I forgot the input `l`.

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, 58 bytes

```
ToExpression@StringReplace[#," "->"+"]~ToString~InputForm&
```

This returns the simplified result. If outputting a rational number instead of a string is fine, we can save 19 bytes:

```
ToExpression@StringReplace[#," "->"+"]&
```

Answer (score 4):

### PowerShell, <s>47</s> <s>44</s> 42 Bytes

<sub>[Crossed out 44 is still regular 44 ;(](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7427/42963)</sub>

```
$l,$n,$d=$args-split'\D';"$(+$l*$d+$n)/$d"
```

Golfed a couple bytes by using regex `-split`. Golfed a couple more thanks to [TessellatingHeckler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/571/tessellatingheckler) by swapping the regex.

The `$args-split'\D'` takes our input argument and splits on non-digit characters. Here it performs two splits, one on whitespace, the other on the `/` character. The results are then stored in the three variables using a simultaneous assignment. We then formulate the string output as (the `$l`eft number times the `$d`enominator plus the `$n`umerator) executed as a code block, a `/` slash, and then the `$d`enominator again.

Comment: Hi, I think you can do `-split ' |/'` to save one character with a "match either this|or that" regex, or use `-split '\D'` to split on anything which isn't a digit and s(h)ave two characters. If @Downgoat is willing to be slightly flexible on the output format, `'{0}*{2}+{1};{2}'-f($args-split'\D')|iex` is 40 bytes and has much cooler output because the numbers are even one above the other!

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Thanks for the regex assist. I've asked Downgoat for input. But `$l,$n,$d=$args-split'\D';+$l*$d+$n;$d` is shorter yet at 37, and logically follows the same pattern as here.

Comment: Oh yeah, just math! (That would be enough to beat a Perl answer, too)

Answer (score 3):

## Java with [Ten Foot Laser Pole](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/Ten-Foot-Laser-Pole) 1.03, 79+25 (import) = 104 bytes

Requires `import sj224.tflp.math.*;`

```
String m(String[]a){return ""+new BigRational(a[0]).add(new BigRational(a[1]));}
```

This will almost certainly work with 1.04 as well, but so far I've only tested it with 1.03 because I already happened to have a java project set up with 1.03 in the build path.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>44</s> 41 bytes

```js
m=>([x,y,z]=m.match(/\d+/g),+y+x*z+"/"+z)
```

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to [@ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions)!*

### Explanation

Very simple.

```js
m=>
  ([x,y,z]=m.match(/\d+/g), // x, y and z = numbers from input
    +y+x*z                  // numerator
    +"/"+z                  // denominator
  )
```

### Test

Test is without destructuring assignment to work in most browsers.

```js
var solution = m=>+(p=m.match(/\d+/g))[1]+p[0]*p[2]+"/"+p[2]
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="11 23/44" />
<button onclick="result.textContent=solution(input.value)">Go</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Nice! You can use `[p,q,r]=` in place of `p=`, then replace `p[0]`, `p[1]`, and `p[2]` with `p`, `q`, and `r`, respectively. After this change, I get 41:`m=>([p,q,r]=m.match(/\d+/g),+q+p*r+"/"+r)`

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks for the tip! I actually did consider using a destructuring assignment but they don't work in Chrome and I didn't have Firefox on hand to test it. :P

Comment: My first crossed out 44! :D

Comment: You can use `m.split(/\W/g)` instead to save a byte

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + coreutils, 28

```bash
dc<<<${@/\// }sarla*+n47Plap
```

`$@` expands to all command-line parameters, so `${@/\// }` expands to all command-line parameters with `/` replaced with  , which is put on `dc`'s stack.  The rest is simple stack manipulation and arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, <s>58</s> 50 bytes

```julia
s->eval(parse((r=replace)(r(s," ","+"),"/","//")))
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts a string and returns a `Rational` type object. To call it, give it a name, e.g. `f=s->...`.

We can take advantage of the fact that the input can be manipulated slightly to be an expression that evaluates to a rational. In particular, an integer plus a rational is a rational, and rationals are denoted with double slashes. So if we turn `4 1/2` into `4+1//2`, the evaluated result will be `9//2`.

Ungolfed:

```julia
function f(s::AbstractString)
    # Replace the space in the input with a plus
    r1 = replace(s, " ", "+")

    # Replace the / with //
    r2 = replace(r1, "/", "//")

    # Parse the resulting expression as a rational
    return eval(parse(r2))
end
```

Answer (score 2):

## Smalltalk – 76 characters

The input exactly matches the array delimiter and inherent fraction representation of Smalltalk. If it just weren't so verbose, it could have been a serious contender!

```
Compiler evaluate:'|p|p:=0.#(',FileStream stdin nextLine,')do:[:q|p:=p+q].p'
```

It's too bad simplification wasn't a requirement, Smalltalk does it automatically!

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>74</s> <s>67</s> 63 bytes

```hs
r=read
f x|(a,(c,s:d):_)<-lex<$>lex x!!0=show(r a*r d+r c)++s:d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v8i2KDUxhStNoaJGI1FHI1mn2CpF0ype00Y3J7XCRsUOSCpUKCoa2BZn5JdrFCkkahUppGgXKSRramsDlf7PTczMsy0oyswrUUlTMjRSMNY3UfoPAA)

### Explanation

As [H.PWiz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71256/h-pwiz) figured out we can use Haskell's lexer here to break up the string into it's parts. (Earlier I was using `span(>'/')`) And Laikoni pointed out that `<$>` works just like `mapSnd` from `Data.Tuple`.

The pattern guard breaks up our code into the three numbers we want using `lex`.  `lex` invokes haskell's lexer to break off the first token.  It returns a list with each element representing a possible way to parse the string.  These elements are tuples with the first element being the first token and the rest of the string being the second element.  Now since the input format is very regular we are only ever going to have exactly one parse, so we can always take the first one.  The first thing we do is invoke `lex` on the input

```hs
lex x
```

Then we unwrap it from it's list giving us a 2-tuple

```hs
lex x!!0
```

The first token will be the whole part of the mixed fraction leaving the fraction prepended by a space to still parse.  Then since tuples are `Functors` we can use `(<$>)` an alias for `fmap` to apply `lex` to the second element of the tuple.

```hs
lex<$>lex x!!0
```

This eats through the space and breaks off the next token, the numerator of our fraction.  Now we bind this to a pattern match using `<-`.  Our pattern is

```hs
(a,(c,s:d):_)
```

`a` grabs the whole part of the fraction, our first token. `:_` unwraps the list resulting from our second `lex`.  `c` grabs the second token we lexed, that is the numerator of the fraction.  Everything that remains is bound to `s:d` which splits it into its first character, guaranteed by the format to be a `/` and the remainder which will be the denominator.

Now that we have parsed the input we do the actual computation:

```hs
show(r a*r d+r c)++s:d
```

Where `r` is the read function we bound earlier.

It is important to note that `lex` returns a list empty if it fails and non-empty if it succeeds.  Why this is not a `Maybe` I do not know.

Comment: [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v8i2KDUxhStNoaImWiNRJ0kz1kY3J7VCoUInWiNZJ94qBSaQZFuckV@uUaSQqFWkkKJdpJCsqa2trq9ulfI/NzEzz7agKDOvRCVNydBIwVjfROk/AA)

Comment: @H.PWiz That is a great use of lex.

Comment: `lex` is just a handy, rarely used function that splits a string into the first token and the rest. It returns as a list, so it can fail with `[]`

Comment: @H.PWiz Do you know why it doesn't return a `Maybe`?

Comment: No, I don;t know a whole lot about it. It uses `Reads`, which I am somewhat ignorant of

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip, I'll snoop around to find out for myself.  I do think `ReadS` is just a type alias btw.

Comment: 65 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcRLDkAwEADQvVMMkWiV@K4adRWZaIWoT4ZEF@5e3uLNeK3GWu9JkUEdTOBehhkbs0FqLgfe5da4Lu7/wYVhqa75eBgBpgRaEIxciKRIpPYbLrs6adnveIqqGpqijfwH "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: You should be able to save another 2 by [matching on the `/`](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v8i2KDUxhStNoaJGI1FHI1mn2CpF0ype00Y3J7XCRsUOSCpUKCoa2BZn5JdrFCkkahUppGgXKSRramsDlf7PTczMsy0oyswrUUlTMjRSMNY3UfoPAA)

Comment: [59 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hokYjUUcjWafYKkXTKl7TRrcoNTGl2EbFDkwrVCgqGtgWZ@SXayRqgUQUUrSTNbW1gar/5yZm5tkWFGXmlaikKRkaKRjrmyj9BwA)

Comment: bump ^ .-.-.-.-.-

Comment: @H.PWiz tbh, I think that could be it's own answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>17</s> 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
#`'/¡R`Š©*+®'/ý
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@MagicOctopusUrn*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fOUFd/9DCoISjCw6t1NI@tE5d//De//9NFAz1jQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/W/i9l85QV3/0MKghKMLDq3U0j60Tl3/8N7/Ov9NFAz1jbgMjRSM9E24DBQMQBxDBSNjfRMTAA).

**Explanation:**

```
#`         # Split input by spaces and push all items to the stack
           #  i.e. "4 1/2" → "4" and "1/2"
  '/¡      # Push the second item by "/"
           #  i.e. "1/2" → [1,2]
     R`    # Revert the list, and also push all items to the stack
           #  i.e. [1,2] → [2,1] → 2 and 1
Š          # Triple-swap the stack
           #  [4,2,1] → [1,4,2]
 ©         # Store the 2 in the register
  *        # Multiple the top two items
           #  4 and 2 → 8
   +       # Add the top two items
           #  1 and 8 → 9
®          # Push the 2 from the register to the stack again
 '/ý       # Join the two items by "/"
           #  9 and 2 → "9/2"
```

---

With flexible input- and output-format, taking the integers in the order `x,z,y` and outputting the nominator and denominator on separated lines it would be **4 bytes** (which is why I added the [parsing](/questions/tagged/parsing)-tag to the challenge..):

```
*+²»
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fS/vQpkO7//834TLiMgQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/W/i5ul5aOV/Le1D6w7t/q9zaJv9fxMuIy5DLkMjLhDDAIwNDblMgDxjAA).

**Explanation:**

```
*        # Multiply the first two inputs (x and z)
         #  i.e. 4 and 2 → 8
 +       # Add the third input (y)
         #  i.e. 8 and 1 → 9
  ²      # Take the second input again (z)
   »     # Join the stack by newlines and implicitly print it
```

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Thanks, but the input-format is different than in the challenge description. Apparently the format (as single string) `4 1/2` is mandatory for this particular challenge. Otherwise I would have used my 4-byte version (or if output was mandatory, but input flexible I would use this 6-byter: [`*+'/²J`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fS1td/9Amr///TbiMuAwB))

Comment: [15-bytes](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fOUFd/9DCoISjCw6t1NI@tE5d//De//@NFEyM9Y0A "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Oh, didn't even knew about "_Push all the items of `a` into the stack_".. o.Ô Exactly what I needed for this challenge! And smart with the join by "/". Thanks! :)

Comment: I hate using the "Push all items of a into the stack" command because it's "`" and it can't be tamed by inline code-tags.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn yeah, it's also a bit annoying in comments (which is why I quoted "_Push all the items of `a` into the stack_" instead of using ``'`'``..

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Using `'`  instead of tile it would be: `''>'<''`. Unfortunately it doesn't work with just a tile and spaces, so it has to be surrounded by other text to use the double-tile.

Comment: ''Oh man, yesss, I've needed this like 10 times''

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 1 byte

```
+
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%2B&i=4+1%2F2%0A12+2%2F4%0A0+0%2F2%0A11+23%2F44&a=1&m=2) (although there's not much to debug)

The challenge specification says "You do not need to simplify the output."  Assuming it's *allowed* to simplify, then there's a built-in instruction in stax to do this.  The input is implicitly interpreted as an integer and a rational number.  The `+` instruction widens both to rationals, adds, and simplifies.  The result is implicitly printed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 92 bytes

```forth
: f 0 -rot 3. do 0 -rot >number 1 m+ loop 2drop + >r swap i * + r> <# 0 #s '/ hold + #s #> ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY3LCsIwFET3fsXQLARLzaNdqeRf1DRWaL3hJiJ@fbwuBNHNDOfAMJG4TN0lvqvWHSIMOqaCfotAH/C3@3IaGRZLi5kowQWWbOEZ@XFMuGIjxB4HJSOVsdaYaA4iBZTHvuYG1sL1ehga@SnPNOLMK9EDrHY/zsD8Oevg9Pe4vgA)

The pain of parsing and formatting...

Takes a string as `pointer length` (gforth standard), and returns a string in the same format.

#### How it works

```forth
: f ( addr u -- addr u )  \ take a string and return a string
  0 -rot      \ ( 0 addr u )
  3. do       \ repeat 3 times...
    0 -rot      \ ( ... 0 0 addr u )
    >number     \ ( ... num 0 addr u ) parse an integer;
                \ `addr` now points to right after the parsed int
    1 m+        \ increment the addr to point to the next integer
  loop        \ end loop ( x y z 0 addr u )
  2drop +     \ discard input string and zero on the top
  >r          \ ( x y R:z ) so the value of z can be copied by `i`
  swap i * +  \ ( x*z+y R:z )
  r>          \ ( x*z+y z )
  <#          \ start formatting the output from the end
  0 #s        \ push z to the output; formatting built-ins take double cells
  '/ hold     \ push a slash
  + #s        \ #s leaves two zeros at the top, so discard one and push x*z+y
  #>          \ finish formatting and get the string ( pointer length )
;
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
⌈E∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLijIhF4oiRIiwiIiwiNCAxLzIiXQ==) -4 thanks to lyxal

```
⌈   # Split on spaces
 E  # Evaluate each
  ∑ # Sum
```

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%8C%88E%E2%88%91%C6%92%5C%2Fj&inputs=5%203%2F5&header=&footer=) for 7 bytes

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore (no clue why, maybe it was a 2.5 build specific thing, it would have been valid at the time though.). [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLijIhF4oiRIiwiIiwiNCAxLzIiXQ==) works though, for 3 bytes.

Comment: @lyxal That doesn't work either, try `0 0/2` for instance

Comment: Husk does it too, so it seems to be allowable

Comment: As does the wolfram answer

Comment: The question says "You do not need to simplify the output.", which means you can if you want - 0/2 simplified is 0

Comment: @lyxal Ah okay.

Comment: [2 bytes with `s` flag](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJzIiwiIiwi4oyIRSIsIiIsIjQgMS8yIl0=)

Answer (score 2):

## Wolfram|Alpha, 0 or 1 byte

```
=
```

The challenge says it's not necessary to simplify the output, but doesn't disallow it.  If it's not disallowed, then:

1)The online Wolfram|Alpha interpreter will automatically convert mixed numbers to improper fractions (0 bytes). E.g.:

[image]

2)The Wolfram|Alpha interpreter can be called within Mathematica by entering `=` followed by the input (1 byte):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
OẸ'//ẸsNṭẊ,p+x,'/j
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPU8lRTElQkElQjgnJTJGJTJGJUUxJUJBJUI4c04lRTElQjklQUQlRTElQkElOEElMkNwJTJCeCUyQyclMkZqJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9JTIyNCUyMDElMkYyJTIyJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwLSUzRSUyMCUyMjklMkYyJTIyJTBBJTIyMTIlMjAyJTJGNCUyMiUyMCUyMCUyMC0lM0UlMjAlMjI1MCUyRjQlMjIlMEElMjIwJTIwMCUyRjIlMjIlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAtJTNFJTIwJTIyMCUyRjIlMjIlMEElMjIxMSUyMDIzJTJGNDQlMjIlMjAtJTNFJTIwJTIyNTA3JTJGNDQlMjImZmxhZ3M9Q2U=)

##### Explanation

```python
OẸ'//ẸsNṭẊ,p+x,'/j  # Implicit input ("x y/z")
OẸ                  # Split on spaces, then dump onto the stack
  '//Ẹ             '# Split the fraction on "/", then dump again
      sN            # Swap and convert the numerator to integer
        ṭ           # Triple swap to get the order [y, x, z]
         Ẋ          # Copy z to the register without popping
          ,p        # Multiply x and z (implicit conversion to int)
            +       # Add this to y (which we converted earlier)
             x,     # Pair this with z (from the register)
               '/j '# Join this pair on "/"
                    # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 43 bytes

```
[ eval( -- x x ) + >fraction [I ${}/${}I] ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=JU29CsIwGNz7FEcQVEpJGzOIgrhJFxfRpXQIkmogJiVG8QefxKWLPoBv49sYDB_HHXfcfc93I7beuu67Wa_K5WICeRYaB-H3UMZL11otvMROGumEVjfhlTVHKItpkhCOgjKSkIKBUR5EjjwaBdiIck5eJ99k429a_YcHyDJcwg2RYta48DvMoSrRuz9oQFmjjpVPv8IcRqMGhxFtq68x6LrIPw)

Assumes the input must be a string, otherwise this can be shorter. Simplifies the output.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, <s>82</s> <s>61</s> 38 bytes

```
#!perl -paF/\D/
$_=$F[0]*$F[2]+$F[1]."/$F[2]"
```

This can probably be golfed more.

**Changes**

- Saved 16 bytes by using a regex in `split`, and 5 by using `<>` instead of `<STDIN>`.
- Saved another 16 bytes thanks to Dennis.

Comment: With shebang `#!perl -paF/\D/` (9 bytes), you can use `$_=$F[0]*$F[2]+$F[1]."/$F[2]"`.

Comment: @Dennis I've added that in. Thanks!

Comment: The `#!perl` part of the shebang and the linefeed do not count. This is only 38 bytes.

Comment: @Dennis Oh, OK. I'll correct it now. (On the bright side I think this is the second-shortest non-esoteric answer)

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <s>159</s> <s>148</s> <s>142</s> <s>120</s> 110 bytes

```
String m(String[]a){Long b=new Long(a[0]),d=new Long((a=a[1].split("/"))[1]);return b*d+new Long(a[0])+"/"+d;}
```

Saved a bunch of bytes thanks to FlagAsSpam.

Comment: @FlagAsSpam Done.

Comment: @FlagAsSpam But then the variables will be left undeclared!

Comment: Disregard all of what I just said - a short way doing what you're doing is `Long b=new Long(a[0]),c=new Long((a=a[1].split("/"))[0]),d=new Long(a[1]);`

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript ES6, 62 bytes

```
p=prompt;b=p(a=+p()).split`/`;alert((+b[1]*a+ +b[0])+"/"+b[1])
```

Comment: Pretty nice! Some tips: You can use `[b,c]=` in place of `b=`, then use `b` in place of `b[0]` and `c` in place of `b[1]`. Also, you can rearrange the equation so you don't need parentheses at all: `p=prompt;[b,c]=p(a=+p()).split`/`;alert(+b+c*a+"/"+c)`

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 51 bytes

```
Interpreter["ComputedNumber"]@#~ToString~InputForm&
```

Interestingly, Mathematica supports this with a built-in. If outputting a number is allowed, than we only need 28 bytes:

```
Interpreter@"ComputedNumber"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 23 bytes

```ruby
->x{eval x.split*?++?r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166iOrUsMUehQq@4ICezRMteW9u@qPZ/QWlJsUJatJKJgqG@kVLsfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), 13 bytes

```lua
a*c+b.."/"..c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/z9RK1k7SU9PSV9JTy/5////hob/jYz/m5gAAA)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the input format `"x y/z"` is mandatory for this particular challenge, but just in case I've asked OP to verify.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) with -la -Mfeature=say, <strike>32 bytes</strike> 25 bytes

```perl
m|/|;say$_*$'+$F[1],"/$'"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z@3Rr/GujixUiVeS0VdW8Ut2jBWR0lfRV3p/38TBUN9Iy5DIwUjfRMuAwUDEMdQwchY38TkX35BSWZ@XvF/3ZzE/7q@aamJJaVFqbZAcwA)

*(-7 bytes thanks to Dom Hastings)*

`$_` is the whole input `x y/z`, which evaluates the value of `x` in numeric contexts (like the `*` here). `$'` is the regex post-match string, which here contains whatever comes after `/` - so, `z`. To get the `y` value, we use the `-a` flag which splits the input on spaces and places them in the `@F` array. So here, `@F = ("x", "y/z")`, which means `$F[1]="y/z"` which evaluates in `y` in numeric contexts (since `y` is the initial contiguous sequence of digits with `$F[1]`).

Comment: You do not have to count the `-p` flag in your byte count; instead you count the language as `Perl 5 with -p flag, 32 bytes`. See [this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/67312) for the current consensus.

Comment: Nice approach! I just had a little go at this and managed to make a 25 byte version: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18/Rl/fujixUiVeS0VdW8Ut2jBWR0lfRV3p/38TBUN9Iy5DIwUjfRMuAwUDEMdQwchY38TkX35BSWZ@XvF/3Rw3/RgXbf3/ur6megaGBgA "Perl 5 – Try It Online"). Using `$'` was the only real difference there really!

Comment: The combination of using both regex-`$'` and `-a`-`$F[n]` to get parts of the string is a pretty good idea, I have to remember that! Thanks, updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>78</s> 76 bytes

```python
def f(s):a,b=s.split();b,c=b.split('/');return'%s/'%(int(a)*int(c)+int(b))+c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BDoIwEETvfMVezHaFUECMEdIvUQ6AJZIaIG09EOO3Y4uYuJfZmbydnWZ7H4fDstxkBx0zVNRRI0xspkdvGZVN1Ipmc8iRSi3tUw@4Mxx3rB8sq2nvpaXQS0MUtouVxhoQ8MIcUp5hAXh2EgGmGWQ898ExceqSBJIvkWxECtmB5xtz8ts76EYNCvoB1uZYydkwKgJwM2n/V7lLgKt1DStyUdWafKOOKfqzDKXWo8YIR4V0@R0I4bmKguUD)

Comment: `return'%s/'%(int(a)*int(c)+int(b))+c` is 2 bytes shorter

Answer (score 1):

## [Ouroboros](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Ouroboros), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
rrry@*+n47oMn1(
```

[Try it here!](http://dloscutoff.github.io/Esolangs/Ouroboros/)

#### Explanation

The reason why Ouroboros is great for this challenge: its integer-reading primitive, `r`, skips over any non-digit characters until it comes to a number. So no parsing is required; we just read three numbers and process them. The example below uses the input `23 11/44`.

```
rrr              Read all three numbers to the local stack
                  Local: 23 11 44
   y             Push a copy of the top of the local stack to the shared stack
                  Local: 23 11 44   Shared: 44
    @            Rotate (moving third item to top of stack)
                  Local: 11 44 23   Shared: 44
     *           Multiply
                  Local: 11 1012    Shared: 44
      +          Add
                  Local: 1023       Shared: 44
       n         Output as number
                                    Shared: 44   Output: 1023
        47       Push 47
                  Local: 47         Shared: 44   Output: 1023
          o      Output as character
                                    Shared: 44   Output: 1023/
           M     Move the top value from the shared stack to the local stack
                  Local: 44                      Output: 1023/
            n    Output as number
                                                 Output: 1023/44
             1(  Terminate
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
Σmrw
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9zi3KLy////mygY6hsBAA)

`ṁrw` is supposed to work, but there's some bug that returns an empty list. Anyway, hooray for native rational number support.

Answer (score 1):

## [GNU AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 5+16 = 21 bytes

Command-line argument: `-F |/`

Source code:

```
$0=$1*$3+$2"/"$3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxcBWxVBLxVhbxUhJX0nF@P9/EwVDfSMuQyMFI30TLgMFAxDHUMHIWN/E5F9@QUlmfl7xf103hRp9AA)

The command-line argument sets the field separator to the regex `/ |\//`. Thus, it is easy to map the input as three fields.

Answer (score 1):

## [Itr](https://github.com/bsoelch/OneChar.js/blob/main/ItrLang.md), 1 byte

`+`

Itr has built-in support for rational numbers, including for parsing input numbers.

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=Kw==&in=MTEgMjMvNDQ=)

### Explanation

```
   ; implicit input, by default numbers are separated by spaces
   ; two integers with a '/' between them are interpreted as a fraction
 + ; add the integer part to the fractional part
   ; implicitly output the fraction
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Headass](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headass), 80 bytes

```
-(----[]]]][]]][{{U]>)D^^D^^^^^R]^}:DON-)}:NE.U[UOUO{^)N+E:]OD-}.U^U[{U^)DPD]P:}
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIiwiIiwiLSgtLS0tW11dXV1bXV1dW3t7VV0+KUReXkReXl5eXlJdXn06RE9OLSl9Ok5FLlVbVU9VT3teKU4rRTpdT0QtfS5VXlVbe1VeKURQRF1QOn0iLCIiLCI0OSAvLyAxXG40OSAvLyAxXG4zMiAvLyBzcGFjZVxuNTAgLy8gMlxuNTEgLy8gM1xuNDcgLy8gL1xuNTIgLy8gNFxuNTIgLy8gNCIsIiJd) Takes character codes as input and outputs as two numbers Numerator, Denominator.

#### Explanation:

Fairly straightforward, parses by looping through digits, subtracting 48, and then multiplying by 10 before adding each new number. when it hits a charcode less than 48, it knows to move on to the next number. There's not an easy way to multiply within a single code block to my knowledge, so the next two code blocks respectively copy a bunch of x onto the queue and then add them all up. Probably still golfable within the same approach, I found a few golfs while writing up the explanation, even.

```
-(----[]]]][]]][{{U]>)D^^D^^^^^R]^}:DON-)}:NE. block 0: parses input
-(                                             r3 = -1
  ----[]]]][]]][                               r2 = -48
                {                     N-)}:    while input remains
                 {U]>)            }:             while input + r2 > r3
                      D^^D^^^^^                    r1 *= 10
                               R]^                 r1 += input + r2
                                    DO           enqueue and reset r1
                                           NE  go to block 1
                                             . end block

U[UOUO{^)N+E:]OD-}. block 1: copies x z times onto queue
U[                  r2 = x
  UO                enqueue y
    UO              enqueue z
    U  ^            r1 = z
      {^)   :  D-}  while(r1--){
             ]O       enqueue x
                    }
         N+E        go to block 2
                  . end code block

U^U[{U^)DPD]P:} block 2: sums copies of x and adds y, prints x*z+y and z
U^              r1 = y
  U[            r2 = z
    {U )     :} while items remain unvisited on the queue (all of which are x)
     U^           r1 += x
        DP      print r1
          D]P   print r2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 25 bytes

```
{m:g/\d+/;$0*$2+$1~"/$2"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcjRCkAwFAbgV/lbJyvU2Y7lgngSJcXcEHG1xKtPyt3Xt0/HUsY1IPFo4rVWM3djxjWZlCQj@ygmUXc8hwBFPZoWlwf1t4LfDmgHy6JzaCsQdp8MzF8WUrBzOr4)

`m:g/\d+/` matches all sequences of digits in the input string, setting the variable `$/` to a list of the matches as a side effect.  `$0` is equivalent to `$/[0]` and so on, so the rest of the function constructs a the output string with the appropriate arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

## C, 64

```c
main(i,d,n){scanf("%d %d/%d",&i,&n,&d);printf("%d/%d",i*d+n,d);}
```

Reads input from STDIN.  Fairly self-explanatory, I think.

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 123 Bytes

```
m=io.read()z=string x=z.find c=z.sub b=tonumber s=x(m," ")f=x(m,"/")d=c(m,f+1)print(b(c(m,1,s))*b(d)+b(c(m,s,f-1)).."/"..d)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Milky Way 1.6.0](https://github.com/zachgates7/Milky-Way), 31 bytes

```
'" "\="/"\=>;<A;A;:>*;A+"/"+<+!
```

Ended up being much longer than I thought it would be.

---

#### Explanation

```
'" "\="/"\=>;<A;A;:>*;A+"/"+<+!

'                                # read input from the command line
 " "  "/"               "/"      # push a string to the stack
    \    \                       # split the STOS at the TOS
     =    =                      # dump the TOS to the stack
           >       >             # rotate the stack rightward
            ;  ; ;   ;           # swap the TOS and STOS
             <              <    # rotate the stack leftward
              A A     A          # push the integer representation of the TOS
                  :              # duplicate the TOS
                    *            # multiply the STOS by the TOS
                       +   + +   # add the TOS and STOS
                              !  # output the TOS
```

---

#### Usage

```
./mw <path-to-code> -i <input>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2.7, 88 Bytes

```
a=input().split('/');print int(a[-1])*int(a[0].split()[0])+int(a[0].split()[1]),'/',a[1]
```

Try it [online](https://repl.it/B9Zf)!

You have to type the input in quotes.

Probably not the best ...

Comment: [76 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9E2M6@gtERDU6@4ICezRENdX13TukKn0jY3sUAjM69EJzHaIBYqp6lpXVAEFEuo0AKSGonRhrGa2pUJ2kA92iDO///qpgqG@kbqAA)

Answer (score 0):

### [Check](https://github.com/ScratchMan544/check-lang), 120 bytes

```
>]+>:>32r#v
#d@0+\)  ##:>4;:>5'=:>48-\R-?
dd)R>32-#v
#>15-#v  #?
47r@>@   #v
#dd#v #?
r@>@     #v
    #\d@\: @*@+pd"/"op
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCoMwEEX3OUUwi2KTUI0Jtikd5wxuG1eOUOii4qLXn45SGPiPx2Pm1zK/mWGykKELm/kqQ9jYUmttTIZ4z5BOD4GrL6MfFFE9Suj3ENokK@GgYr8hoBbeH5BYkX91yGMKYckaz2hXqi7VZ2XmZ7w5uS641LjUuti7JBymHw)

I might be able to save some bytes by not trying to reuse the parsing loop (the second line). That way I could make the loop more specific, avoid the huge mess of conditionals, and I could use the register for other things.

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 112 bytes

```c#
s=>{string[]a=s.Split(),b=a[1].Split('/');int o=int.Parse(b[1]);return int.Parse(a[0])*o+int.Parse(b[0])+"/"+o;}
```

Full/Formatted Version:

```c#
namespace System.Linq
{
    class P
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Func<string, string> f = s =>
            {
                string[] a = s.Split(), b = a[1].Split('/');
                int o = int.Parse(b[1]);
                return int.Parse(a[0]) * o + int.Parse(b[0]) + "/" + o;
            };

            Console.WriteLine(f("4 1/2"));
            Console.WriteLine(f("12 2/4"));
            Console.WriteLine(f("0 0/2"));
            Console.WriteLine(f("11 23/44"));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 31 bytes

```apl
∊∘(⍕¨⊃,⍨'/',⍨⊃⊥1∘↓)¯1⌽#⍎¨∊∘⎕D⊆⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHHV2POmZoPOqdemjFo65mnUe9K9T11UEUkPeoa6khUPZR22TNQ@sNH/XsVX7U2wdUB9bzqG@qy6Outkddi4AmKagbGioYGeubmKgDAA)

Thanks to ngn for the `⊃⊥1∘↓` trick

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, 65 Bytes

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJReZqugZGRgoGBoqm9koGTNZW8HlLTV0FBJtC0oSk2PLy7IySzRUNKPjinWidGP1VfSAevS1Iw2iNVSSYw2itUGkoaxmnpK@kp6YAHr//8B)

**Code**

```
<?=(($a=preg_split("/[\s,\/]/",$argv))[0]*$a[2]+$a[1])."/".$a[2];
```

**Explanation**

```
$a=preg_split("/[\s,\/]/",$argv); # Split the string on "/" and " "
(($a)[0]*$a[2]+$a[1]) # as always denominator*whole number + numerator 
."/"                  # echo an slash
.$a[2];               # echo de denominator
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 10, 87 bytes

A lambda from `String` to `String`.

```java
s->{var p=s.split(" |/");return new Long(p[0])*new Long(p[2])+new Long(p[1])+"/"+p[2];}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##jY8/b8IwEMXn5FOcPNml2KH/VCnA2KlMjCiDG5LIqXEs@xyEIJ89NQoD6tJO73733knvWtnLebv/Hm340qqEUkvvYSOVgXOa3JYeJUaplZEa2njBAyrN62BKVJ3hH7dhuUWnTPMIk66hhtXo5@tzLx3YlefeaoWUwEUQlrsKgzNgqiN8dqahdpcV7OEOnwo2u8NFRCLI7Grkw5jk6e@Cfaf2cIjd6VRgV4B0jWfXV5LtyWN14F1AbqOJ2tCaS2v1iZI3eBavhLH8j1wGL@L9X7lMLKbckA7jDw)